# Angular2: how to use bootstrap-tagsinput properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, systemjs, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm trying to use [bootstrap-tagsinput](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput) library in my Angular2 project. The library is installed using `package.json` file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
    ...
  }
```

Now I have a `bootstrap-tagsinput` folder in `node_modules`. I want to use tagsinput in a specific component. I saw there is a `bootstrap-tagsinput-angular.js` file in the `node_modules/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist` directory, but I can't managed to use it properly.

**Am I supposed to add the JS file in my index.html so bootstrap-tagsinput will be available for all components? Or is there a way to import it just where it is needed?**

In other way, is there a way to do something like this:

mycomponent.component.html:

```
<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput"/>
```

mycomponent.component.ts:

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TagsInputComponents} from 'bootstrap-tagsinput'; // Something like that?!?

@Component({
    ...
})

export class MyComponentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit():any {
        $('input').tagsinput('refresh');
    }
}
```

thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I can see some issue in using bootstrap-tags-input with angular batter to use ngTagsInput if you using angular.

Please see more details at : [ngTagsInput](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngTagsInput) , [demo](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos)

Comment: can we use ngTagsInput with Angular 2?

Answer (score 2):

the boostrap-tagsinput is a directive. So you can need somethings as follow:

Step 1: Import boostrap-tagsinput

```
import {TagsInputComponents} from 'bootstrap-tagsinput';
```

Step 2: Add to directives

```
@Component({
    ...
    directives: [TagsInputComponents],
    ...
})
```

then use it in your view.

Hope this help!

Comment: Cannot check right now but `import {TagsInputComponents} from 'bootstrap-tagsinput';` was not a valid syntax (error in my IDE - Webstorm). Have you managed to use the component this way personnaly?

Comment: You can either convert boostrap-tagsinput to use in angular2 or use angular2-tag-input at [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tag-input)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an easier solution. I ended up using [angular2-tag-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tag-input)

First you'll have to run your node command prompt

```
npm install angular2-tag-input --save
```

Then include it in your module

```
// In one of your application NgModules
import {RlTagInputModule} from 'angular2-tag-input';


    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RlTagInputModule
      ]
    })


// In one of your component templates
<rl-tag-input [(ngModel)]="tags" placeholder="Testing placeholder"></rl-tag-input>

// In one of your component ts file
var tags= ['tag1','tag2','tag3']
```